# How to create a new json row by combining elements from multiple other json rows dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have json data in fields that are split across rows. I want to have all these fields in a single row. I would like to write a javascript function that takes the original input and produces the output. I am very new to javascript. I would like to do this in a dynamic way so that I don't have to explicitly name the new fields -- rather iterate through all the fields in each row one by one and append them to a new row, with the same names/values. Thanks in advance.

Starting json:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sara Smith",
        "dob": "19831002"
    },
    {
        "title": "director",
        "emails": [
            "ssmith@gmail.com",
            "sarasmith@yahoo.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        "phones": [
            {
                "type": "home",
                "number": "3452345432"
            },
            {
                "type": "work",
                "number": "3452345343"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Desired end state json:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sara Smith",
        "dob": "19831002"
        "title": "director",
        "emails": [
            "ssmith@gmail.com",
            "sarasmith@yahoo.com"
        ]
        "phones": [
            {
                "type": "home",
                "number": "3452345432"
            },
            {
                "type": "work",
                "number": "3452345343"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried ... oh, wait, you got answers already ... you are blessed

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce`:

```js
const startJSON = [{
    "name": "Sara Smith",
    "dob": "19831002"
  },
  {
    "title": "director",
    "emails": [
      "ssmith@gmail.com",
      "sarasmith@yahoo.com"
    ]
  },
  {
    "phones": [{
        "type": "home",
        "number": "3452345432"
      },
      {
        "type": "work",
        "number": "3452345343"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const endJSON = [startJSON.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }))];

console.log(endJSON);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in combination with [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const input = [
  {"name": "Sara Smith", "dob": "19831002"},
  {
    "title": "director",
    "emails": ["ssmith@gmail.com", "sarasmith@yahoo.com"]
  },
  {
    "phones": [
      {"type": "home", "number": "3452345432"},
      {"type": "work", "number": "3452345343"}
    ]
  }
];

let output = input.reduce((acc, curr) =>
{
    Object.assign(acc[0], curr);
    return acc;
}, [{}]);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```